# Is there a tool to print the network topology structure in Linux?

Tags: networking

Is there a tool to print the network connection structure?

in my CentOS server, there are a lot interfaces which created by other services.

```
[root@att ~]# dumpcap -D
1. bridge0
2. docker0
3. nflog
4. nfqueue
5. em1
6. usbmon1
7. em2
8. veth8b8f97a
9. vethfe9fbcf
10. br-eb92c719d431
11. veth5587e98
12. any
13. lo (Loopback)
```

So, is there any tool for describing the connection of network topology? then we can take easy analysis.

---

**EDIT-01**

I use yum installed plotnetcfg:

```
# plotnetcfg --version
v0.4.1
```

and I want to generate the pdf,
but get the error:

```
# plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf
ERROR: Invalid argument
```

---

**EDIT-02**

```
[dele@att root]$ plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf
bash: output.pdf: permission denied
Must be run under root (or with enough capabilities).
```

---

**EDIT-03**

```
[dele@att ~]$ cd; sudo plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf
ERROR: Invalid argument
```

---

**EDIT-04**

I strace plotnetcfg, get below information:

```
[root@att ~]# strace plotnetcfg | grep EINVAL
execve("/usr/sbin/plotnetcfg", ["plotnetcfg"], 0x7ffff0bc5840 /* 28 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xe24000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbadaa2a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (the directory does not exists)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=91401, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 91401, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbadaa13000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libjansson.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=53944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2146960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbada5fd000
mprotect(0x7fbada609000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbada808000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7fbada808000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156240, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbada22f000
mprotect(0x7fbada3f2000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbada5f2000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7fbada5f2000
mmap(0x7fbada5f8000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbada5f8000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbadaa12000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbadaa10000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbadaa10740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbada5f2000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbada808000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x609000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fbadaa2b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbadaa13000, 91401)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xe24000
brk(0xe45000)                           = 0xe45000
brk(NULL)                               = 0xe45000
capget({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_1, pid=0}, {effective=1<<CAP_CHOWN|1<<CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|1<<CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|1<<CAP_FOWNER|1<<CAP_FSETID|1<<CAP_KILL|1<<CAP_SETGID|1<<CAP_SETUID|1<<CAP_SETPCAP|1<<CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|1<<CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|1<<CAP_NET_BROADCAST|1<<CAP_NET_ADMIN|1<<CAP_NET_RAW|1<<CAP_IPC_LOCK|1<<CAP_IPC_OWNER|1<<CAP_SYS_MODULE|1<<CAP_SYS_RAWIO|1<<CAP_SYS_CHROOT|1<<CAP_SYS_PTRACE|1<<CAP_SYS_PACCT|1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN|1<<CAP_SYS_BOOT|1<<CAP_SYS_NICE|1<<CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|1<<CAP_SYS_TIME|1<<CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|1<<CAP_MKNOD|1<<CAP_LEASE|1<<CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|1<<CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|1<<CAP_SETFCAP, permitted=1<<CAP_CHOWN|1<<CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|1<<CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|1<<CAP_FOWNER|1<<CAP_FSETID|1<<CAP_KILL|1<<CAP_SETGID|1<<CAP_SETUID|1<<CAP_SETPCAP|1<<CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|1<<CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|1<<CAP_NET_BROADCAST|1<<CAP_NET_ADMIN|1<<CAP_NET_RAW|1<<CAP_IPC_LOCK|1<<CAP_IPC_OWNER|1<<CAP_SYS_MODULE|1<<CAP_SYS_RAWIO|1<<CAP_SYS_CHROOT|1<<CAP_SYS_PTRACE|1<<CAP_SYS_PACCT|1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN|1<<CAP_SYS_BOOT|1<<CAP_SYS_NICE|1<<CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|1<<CAP_SYS_TIME|1<<CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|1<<CAP_MKNOD|1<<CAP_LEASE|1<<CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|1<<CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|1<<CAP_SETFCAP, inheritable=0}) = 0
open("/proc/1/ns/net", O_RDONLY)        = 3
setns(3, CLONE_NEWNET)                  = 0
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_GENERIC) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=1763448, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=36, type=nlctrl, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST, seq=1, pid=0}, "\x03\x01\x00\x00"}, iov_len=20}, {iov_base={len=131086, type=0x766f /* GENERIC_FAMILY_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_INTR|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED|0x5f40, seq=1919905910, pid=116}, iov_len=16}], msg_iovlen=2, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=184, type=nlctrl, flags=0, seq=1, pid=1763448}, "\x01\x02\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x02\x00\x6f\x76\x73\x5f\x76\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x03\x00"...}, iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 184
close(3)                                = 0
readlink("/proc/1/ns/net", "net:[4026531956]", 4096) = 16
open("/proc/1/ns/net", O_RDONLY)        = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/netns", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
getdents(4, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 96
open("/var/run/netns/net2", O_RDONLY)   = 5
setns(5, CLONE_NEWNET)                  = -1 EINVAL (invalid param)
write(2, "ERROR: Invalid argument\n", 24ERROR: Invalid argument
) = 24
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there’s Jiri Benc’s [`plotnetcfg`](https://github.com/jbenc/plotnetcfg), which will produce diagrams summarising a host’s network interfaces and bridges (including connections and network namespaces):

[image: plotnetcfg network configuration diagram]

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me.

Comment: but when I use the command: `plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf | okular -`, there get error: `ERROR: Invalid argument
okular: cannot connect to X server `

Comment: That’s nothing to do with `plotnetcfg`, it’s because of your X setup, or because you’re running as root and root doesn’t have access to your X server. Try `plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf` and copy `output.pdf` somewhere you can access it as a regular user.

Comment: nice it even discovers network namespaces.

Comment: Please check my edit, I don't know why can not use the trick like you.

Comment: You need to run in a directory where you can write, and you need to run `plotnetcfg` as root. So `cd; sudo plotnetcfg | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf`.

Comment: not those reason, I still get `ERROR: Invalid argument`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were asking about your second edit. The “ERROR” message comes from `plotnetcfg`, but I don’t know what could be causing it; to figure that out, you’d have to run `sudo strace plotnetcfg` and look for `EINVAL`.

Comment: I have updated my post now.